# How can I make all the objects to move between the waypoints?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovementSpeedController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> objectsToMove = new List<Transform>();
    public List<Vector3> positions = new List<Vector3>();
    public int amountOfPositions = 30;
    public int minRandRange, maxRandRange;
    public bool randomPositions = false;
    public bool generateNewPositions = false;
    public float duration = 5f;
    public bool pingPong = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        if (generateNewPositions || (positions.Count == 0 && amountOfPositions > 0))
            GeneratePositions();

        StartCoroutine(MoveBetweenPositions(duration));
    }

    private void GeneratePositions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfPositions; i++)
        {
            if (randomPositions)
            {
                var randPosX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                var randPosY = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                var randPosZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(minRandRange, maxRandRange);
                positions.Add(new Vector3(randPosX, randPosY, randPosZ));
            }
            else
            {
                positions.Add(new Vector3(i, i, i));
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator MoveBetweenPositions(float duration)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count; i++)
        {
            float time = 0;
            Vector3 startPosition = objectsToMove[0].position;

            while (time < duration)
            {
                objectsToMove[0].position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, positions[i], time / duration);
                time += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return null;
            }

            objectsToMove[0].position = positions[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Now only the first object in `objectsToMove` is moving between the waypoints but I need all of the elements of `objectsToMove` to move between the waypoints. If I try this:

```
objectsToMove[i].position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, positions[i], time / duration);
```

I will let out of bound index exception because the size of `objectsToMove` is not the same the size of `positions[i]`

Comment: You can't use `i` on objectsToMove because i belongs to the positions iteration. It's iterating the count of positions. If that is to work, you'll need to have the same count of objects as the positions array. Do you want all the objects to go through the same positions together or go to random positions from the positions list?

Comment: @DinukaJay random yes.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion best thing to do is:

To make one movement script and to attach it to *each* object, so that each object can run its own movement script **separately**.
Then just fire moving command to each object, and pass them a path where you store all waypoints. It could look something like this:

```
 myGameObject.GetComponent<theMovingScript>().TakePathAndGoNow(positions);
```

Because now you are trying to iterate through waypoints, and also iterate through gameObjects, and things get messy quick.

Think of your game objects as , well .. separate objects and let each run its own logic.
In Unity you can write one script and attach it to many objects - and now your objects can have their own speeds, go to different paths etc, even it is really only one script file.

In short: let Unity do the heavy work for you.